# CSS and JQuery files are not loaded when hosting ASP.NET MVC file on Arvixe

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have developed an ASP.Net MVC application and I have deployed it on Arvixe hosting. The website is working fine on my localhost and on windows azure app service. The website: http://seelzahnarzt.de/

The problem appears on Arvixe hosting only. The pages except the home page are not loading the CSS and the javascript files and I receive in the console this error

> ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Besides, I am receiving this error also in the console and the bootstrap functionality including the navbar in mobile devices are not working

> Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

My bundle files are:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/javascript").Include(
                        "~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
                        "~/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
                        "~/js/lightbox.min.js",
                        "~/js/typeahead.jquery.min.js",
                        "~/js/nice-select.min.js",
                        "~/js/wow.min.js",
                        "~/js/custom.js",
                        "~/js/site.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/css/font-awesome.min.css",
```

The includes are:

```
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("/bundles/javascript")
</body>
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve these problems?

Comment: From the error message, it seems this is SSL issue. Are you using SSL on your site? Or maybe your site redirect to https?

Comment: This server could not prove that it is seelzahnarzt.de; its security certificate is from *.win.arvixe.com.

Comment: I contacted Arvixe yesterday and shut down the SSL and want to use the normal http on the website. Apparently, they didn't fix it correctly.

Comment: @SamySammour I see your site http://seelzahnarzt.de/ is working fine now. Which is not working?